# JavaFX - resizing simple application causes "flickering" due to canvas clearing/repaint

Tags: java, performance, user-interface, javafx, canvas

I've got this dead simple project that basically draws a black circle in the middle of a JavaFX Scene Canvas and grows it every 50ms.

Here's my Controller:

```
public class PrimaryController {

    public StackPane theRootPane;
    public CanvasPane theCanvasPane;
    int i = 1;

    public void initialize() {
        theCanvasPane  = new CanvasPane(500, 300);
        theRootPane.getChildren().addAll(theCanvasPane);

        Timeline theTimeline =
            new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(50), actionEvent -> UpdateCanvas(i++)));
        theTimeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        theTimeline.play();
    }

    private void UpdateCanvas(int diameter) {
        theCanvasPane.DrawCircleAtCenterOfCanvas(diameter);
    }
```

Here's my CanvasPane class:

```
public class CanvasPane extends Pane {

private final Canvas theCanvas;
private GraphicsContext theGC;

public CanvasPane(double width, double height) {
    setWidth(width);
    setHeight(height);
    theCanvas = new Canvas(width, height);
    theGC = theCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    getChildren().add(theCanvas);
    theCanvas.widthProperty().bind(this.widthProperty());
    theCanvas.heightProperty().bind(this.heightProperty());
    theCanvas.widthProperty().addListener(observable -> RedrawCanvas());
    theCanvas.heightProperty().addListener(observable -> RedrawCanvas());
}

private void RedrawCanvas() {
    ClearCanvas();
}

private void ClearCanvas() {
    theGC.clearRect(0, 0, theCanvas.widthProperty().doubleValue(),   theCanvas.heightProperty().doubleValue());
}

public void DrawCircleAtCenterOfCanvas(int diameter) {
    double centreX = theCanvas.widthProperty().doubleValue() / 2;
    double centreY = theCanvas.heightProperty().doubleValue() / 2;
    theGC.fillOval(centreX - diameter / 2.0, centreY - diameter / 2.0, diameter, diameter);
}
```

}

Finally, here's my App class and my .fxml

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("primary"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        //stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

primary.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<StackPane fx:id="theRootPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.xxx.PrimaryController" />
```

It works fine until I resize the window, at which point, the canvas is redrawn by clearing it and then painting the new larger circle on the canvas.  This "clearing" of the canvas presents as flicker when the form is resized.

What is a better way of doing this? I'm fudging around with JavaFX after learning Java and getting into UI and animations.  I'm thinking canvas is **not** the way to go...

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just add a Circle Shape object to the scene graph. I don't understand why everybody seems to choose the Canvas for things it is not well suited for.

Comment: java naming conventions please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably better to update the canvas in a `ChangeListener` rather than an `InvalidationListener`, which will result in fewer redraws. Either way you should either:

1. ensure you redraw the circle when the canvas size changes (with your current code, you clear the canvas as soon as the canvas changes size, but don't redraw the circle until the next keyframe, so you end up with some blank canvases in between):

   ```
    public class CanvasPane extends Pane {

        private final Canvas theCanvas;
        private GraphicsContext theGC;

        private int currentDiameter ;

        public CanvasPane(double width, double height) {
            setWidth(width);
            setHeight(height);
            theCanvas = new Canvas(width, height);
            theGC = theCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

            getChildren().add(theCanvas);
            theCanvas.widthProperty().bind(this.widthProperty());
            theCanvas.heightProperty().bind(this.heightProperty());
            theCanvas.widthProperty().addListener((obs, oldWidth, newWidth) -> redrawCanvas());
            theCanvas.heightProperty().addListener((obs, oldHeight, newHeight) -> redrawCanvas());
        }

        public void increaseDiameter() {
            currentDiameter++;
            redrawCanvas();
        }

        private void redrawCanvas() {
            clearCanvas();
            drawCircleAtCenterOfCanvas();
        }

        private void clearCanvas() {
            theGC.clearRect(0, 0, theCanvas.widthProperty().doubleValue(), theCanvas.heightProperty().doubleValue());
        }

        public void drawCircleAtCenterOfCanvas() {
            currentDiameter = currentDiameter ;
            double centreX = theCanvas.widthProperty().doubleValue() / 2;
            double centreY = theCanvas.heightProperty().doubleValue() / 2;
            theGC.fillOval(centreX - currentDiameter / 2.0, centreY - currentDiameter / 2.0, currentDiameter, currentDiameter);
        }
    }
   ```

   and

   ```
   public class PrimaryController {

        @FXML
        private StackPane theRootPane;
        @FXML
        private CanvasPane theCanvasPane;

        public void initialize() {
            theCanvasPane  = new CanvasPane(500, 300);
            theRootPane.getChildren().addAll(theCanvasPane);

            Timeline theTimeline =
                new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(50), actionEvent -> updateCanvas()));
            theTimeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            theTimeline.play();
        }

        private void updateCanvas() {
            theCanvasPane.increaseDiameter();
        }
    }
   ```
2. or (probably better, and far easier for this example) use a `Circle` instead of a canvas:

   ```
    public class PrimaryController {

        @FXML
        private StackPane theRootPane;

        private Circle circle ;

        public void initialize() {

            circle = new Circle();
            theRootPane.getChildren().addAll(circle);

            Timeline theTimeline =
                new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(50), actionEvent -> updateCircle()));
            theTimeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            theTimeline.play();
        }

        private void updateCircle() {
            circle.setRadius(circle.getRadius()+0.5);
        }
    }
   ```